# Materialized view logs questions

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have a materialized view based on two or more other materialized views. I want to schedule fast refresh for the materialized view but the issue is that it does not have any logs, so I must create the logs first. I am new to materialized views so I am not sure how to go about creating the logs for the two underlying materialized views. Do I create a log for each underlying table that is utilized by those views?

Comment: Mv logs should be made for base table of your underlying mvs as well as on the underlying mv also. If you could share the mv details, we would be able to help you in detail

Comment: So if the mv is created on another mv with a self join and that mv is based on somewhere around 8 tables, I would need 9 logs? One the underlying mv and eight for the underlying tables?

Comment: Yes. You correctly understood. And please note that logs are required for fast refresh only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want everything to be fast refreshable, you need MV logs on the:

- base tables
- MVs underlying the "final" MV

You create MV logs on an MV in the same way as regular tables:

```
create table t1 (
  c1 int primary key, c2 int
);
create table t2 (
  c1 int, c2 int, primary key ( c1, c2 )
);

create materialized view log on t1
  with rowid, primary key ( c2 )
  including new values;

create materialized view log on t2
  with rowid, primary key
  including new values;

create materialized view mv1
refresh fast on commit as
  select * from t1;

create materialized view mv2 
refresh fast on commit as
  select * from t2;

create materialized view log on mv1
  with rowid ( c1, c2 )
  including new values;
create materialized view log on mv2
  with rowid ( c1, c2 )
  including new values;

create materialized view mv3 
refresh fast on commit as
  select mv1.c1, count (*) 
  from   mv1 
  join   mv2
  on     mv1.c1 = mv2.c1
  group  by mv1.c1;

insert into t1 values ( 1, 1 );
insert into t1 values ( 2, 2 );

insert into t2 values ( 1, 1 );
insert into t2 values ( 1, 2 );
insert into t2 values ( 2, 2 );

commit;

select * from mv3;

        C1   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          1
```

Comment: I just mean the one based on other MVs; in this example MV3. You need to create logs on all objects in the dependency chain except MV3.